# Find all pair shortest path in a large scale of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I want to find all pair shortest path in a large scale of graph. What can I do? In the mean time, is there any kind of stream algorithm to solve all pair shortest path problem in stream graph?

Comment: Floyd algorithm? what is the definition of stream graph?

Comment: Floyd is useful in a traditional graph. In stream graph, the edges come one by one and the graph structure is changeable.

Comment: just google `dynamic all pair shortest path`

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the hint of @[sudomakeinstall2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040597/sudomakeinstall2), I find something interesting to solve dynamical graph problem. Camil Demetrescu's page A New Approach to Dynamic All Pairs Shortest Paths is great one for this problem. They yield a fully dynamic algorithm for general directed graphs with non-negative real- valued edge weights that supports any sequence of operations in O(n2log3n) amortized time per update and unit worst-case time per distance query, where n is the number of vertices